# BigCommerce v3 API endpoint for Currency

Tags: api, bigcommerce

Can anybody direct me to Bigcommerce API v3 Endpoint for getting default currency?
I am able to get the v2(/stores/{store_hash}/v2/currencies) endpoint but I want the v3 endpoint.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no V3 endpoint for that information yet.

Two methods of getting default currency:

`/v2/store` will list the default currency along with lots of other store information

`/v2/currencies` will list all configured store *display* currencies, and the default (transactional) currency is clear notated.